# Winforms application on Rider gives the error: 'Could not load file or assembly 'EnvDTE, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral...'

Tags: c#, winforms, rider

I am trying to switch to the Rider IDE. I normally work on WinForms applications on Visual Studio. Now, I cannot load my old applications on Rider and I get an error.
Is there a way to fix this?

The Error Message is:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'EnvDTE, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'EnvDTE, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>      at DevExpress.Utils.Design.ProjectHelper.AddReference(IServiceProvider provider, String assembly)
>      at DevExpress.DataAccess.Design.VSSqlDataSourceDesigner.Initialize(IComponent component)
>      at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.AddToContainerPostProcess(IComponent component, String name, IContainer containerToAddTo)
>      at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.PerformAdd(IComponent component, String name)
>      at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.CreateComponent(Type componentType, String name)
>      at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
>      at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
>      at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.ComponentCodeDomSerializer.DeserializeInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Type type, Object[] parameters, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
>      at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeExpression expression)
>      at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.DeserializeStatementToInstance(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeStatement statement)
>      at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object codeObject)
>      at JetBrains.ReSharper.Features.WinForms.Designer.External.Serialization.JetProjectResourceComponentCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object codeObject)
>      at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.DeserializeName(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, String name, CodeStatementCollection statements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the assembly EnvDTE.dll and install it in the Global Assembly Cache or reference it in the Visual Studio project.